# Displaying data from different tables in Laravel in a single view

Tags: php, laravel, database, sqlite, laravel-blade

In the view im trying do display two rows from tables 'categories' and 'suppliers'
categories->category_name and suppliers->company.
The problem is that in each row od displayed data i should acces the edit, delete and update
button which requests id of each purchase.
For now everything is working fine but i can not display these two rows.
The function show_purchases() is responsible For that.

**Controller**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Suppliers;
use App\Models\Categories;
use App\Models\Purchases;

class Purchases_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function show_purchases()
    {
        return view('bookmarks.purchases.show_purchases',
            ['purchases' => Purchases::paginate(10)]);
    }

    public function make_purchase()
    {
        $categories = Categories::get();
        $suppliers = Suppliers::get();

        return view('bookmarks.purchases.make_purchase', 
             compact('categories', 'suppliers'));
    }

    public function store_purchase_data(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'purchased_product' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:50'],
            'categories' => 'required',
            'purchase_price' => ['required', 'min:1'],
            'quantity' => ['required', 'min:1'],
            'expiration_date' => ['required'],
            'suppliers' => 'required',
            'total_purchase_price',
        ]);

        $total = $request->quantity * $request->purchase_price;

        Purchases::create([
            'purchased_product' => $request->purchased_product,
            'category_id' => $request->categories,
            'supplier_id' => $request->suppliers,
            'purchase_price' => $request->purchase_price,
            'quantity' => $request->quantity,
            'expiration_date' => $request->expiration_date,
            'total_purchase_price' => $total,
        ]);

        return redirect('/purchases/show_purchases')
            ->with('message', 'Purchase created successfully!');
    }

    // Show edit form
    public function edit_purchase(Purchases $purchases)
    {
        $categories = Categories::get();
        $suppliers = Suppliers::get();
        
        return view('bookmarks.purchases.edit_purchase', 
            compact('categories', 'suppliers'),
            ['purchases' => $purchases]);
    }

    public function update_purchase(Request $request, Purchases $purchases)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'purchased_product' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:50'],
            'categories' => 'required',
            'purchase_price' => ['required', 'min:1'],
            'quantity' => ['required', 'min:1'],
            'expiration_date' => ['required'],
            'suppliers' => 'required',
        ]);

        $purchases->update([
            'purchased_product' => $request->purchased_product,
            'category_id' => $request->categories,
            'supplier_id' => $request->suppliers,
            'purchase_price' => $request->purchase_price,
            'quantity' => $request->quantity,
            'expiration_date' => $request->expiration_date,
        ]);

        return redirect('/purchases/show_purchases')
            ->with('message', 'Purchase updated successfully!');
    }

    public function delete_purchase(Purchases $purchases)
    {
        $purchases->delete();

        return redirect('/purchases/show_purchases')
            ->with('message', 'Purchase deleted successfully');
    }

    public function auto_purchase()
    {
        return redirect('/suppliers/show_purchases')
            ->with('message', 'Product will be purchased again as scheduled');
    }
}
```

**View/Blade**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')

    <div class="container p-4">
        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Medicine</th>
                    <th scope="col">Category</th>
                    <th scope="col">Supplier</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cost</th>
                    <th scope="col">Total Cost</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                    <th scope="col">Expiration date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                    <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                    <th scope="col">Auto-purchase</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="table-group-divider">
                @foreach($purchases as $purchase)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$purchase->purchased_product}}</td>
                        <td>{{$purchase->category_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$purchase->company}}</td>
                        <td>{{$purchase->purchase_price}}</td>
                        <td>{{$purchase->total_purchase_price}}</td>
                        <td>{{$purchase->quantity}}</td>
                        <td>{{$purchase->expiration_date}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/purchases/{{$purchase->id}}/edit">
                                <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form method="POST" action="/purchases/{{$purchase->id}}">

                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="bi bi-trash3-fill"></i></button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/purchases/{{$purchase->id}}/auto_purchase">
                                <i class="bi bi-arrow-repeat"></i></a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>

            @if(count($purchases)==0)
                <p>no purchases found</p>
            @endif

            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/purchases/make_purchase" role="button">Add purchase</a>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/purchases/show_purchases', [Purchases_Controller::class, 'show_purchases']);
Route::get('/purchases/make_purchase', [Purchases_Controller::class, 'make_purchase']);
Route::post('/purchases', [Purchases_Controller::class, 'store_purchase_data']);
Route::get('/purchases/{purchases}/edit', [Purchases_Controller::class, 'edit_purchase']);
Route::put('/purchases/{purchases}', [Purchases_Controller::class, 'update_purchase']);
Route::delete('/purchases/{purchases}', [Purchases_Controller::class, 'delete_purchase']);
Route::get('/purchases/auto_purchase', [Purchases_Controller::class, 'auto_purchase']);
```

**Model**

```
class Purchases extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'purchased_product','category_id','supplier_id',
        'purchase_price','quantity','total_purchase_price' ,'expiration_date','image'
        
    ];

    protected $table = "purchases";

    public function suppliers(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Suppliers::class);
    }

    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class);
    }
}
```

[Looks like that for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44fzW.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly and what you want to do, then the correct thing would be for you to retrieve the information of categories and suppliers of purchases using the "dynamic property":

```php
{{-- VIEW --}}
@extends('layout')
@section('content')

<div class="container p-4">

<div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {{-- <th scope="col">Name</th> --}}
        <th scope="col">Medicine</th>
        <th scope="col">Category</th>
        <th scope="col">Supplier</th>
        <th scope="col">Cost</th>
        <th scope="col">Total Cost</th>
        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
        <th scope="col">Expiration date</th>
        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        <th scope="col">Auto-purchase</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-group-divider">
      

    @foreach($purchases as $purchase) 

      <tr>
        <td>{{$purchase->purchased_product}}</td>
        <td>{{$purchase->categories->category_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$purchase->suppliers->company}}</td>
        <td>{{$purchase->purchase_price}}</td>
        <td>{{$purchase->total_purchase_price}}</td>
        <td>{{$purchase->quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{$purchase->expiration_date}}</td>

        <td>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/purchases/{{$purchase->id}}/edit">
                <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>
            
        </td>
        <td>
          <form method="POST" action="/purchases/{{$purchase->id}}">

            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="bi bi-trash3-fill"></i></button>

        </form>
        </td>


        <td>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/purchases/{{$purchase->id}}/auto_purchase">
              <i class="bi bi-arrow-repeat"></i></a>
            
        </td>

      </tr>

    @endforeach

    </tbody>
  </table>

  @if(count($purchases)==0)
  <p>no purchases found</p>
  @endif

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/purchases/make_purchase" role="button">Add purchase</a>

</div>

</div>



@endsection
```

[Check it out](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Answer (score -1):

i used a query and it solved my problem

```
            ->join('suppliers', 'suppliers.id', '=', 'purchases.supplier_id')
            ->get(['suppliers.company', 'categories.category_name', 'purchases.purchase_price', 'purchases.quantity', 'purchases.expiration_date',
            'purchases.purchased_product', 'purchases.total_purchase_price', 'purchases.id']);
```

```
      <tr>
        <td>{{$row->purchased_product}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->category_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->company}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->purchase_price}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->total_purchase_price}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->expiration_date}}</td>

        <td>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/purchases/{{$row->id}}/edit">
                <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>
            
        </td>
        <td>
          <form method="POST" action="/purchases/{{$row->id}}">

            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="bi bi-trash3-fill"></i></button>

        </form>
        </td>
```